# Model instance does not want to be created

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create a model instance from my code, and I pass all needed (and not null) parameters, but I'm getting 500 error which says that new_ip is None. How can I investigate the problem more deeply?

```
new_ip = IP(pool=new_adapter.get_ip_pool(), vds_interface=new_adapter, ip=ip)
new_ip.save()
```

P.S. ip is string, the field is IPAddressField.

Comment: `new_ip` can't be `None` if it is really model instance. Are you sure you haven't imported another object with name `IP`? Function that returns nothing for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try this

```
new_ip = IP.objects.create(pool=new_adapter.get_ip_pool(), vds_interface=new_adapter, ip=ip)
```